# Add 30 days to a date in lightning helper js for localizationService fucntion

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I want to add 30 days to the date which I am initializing in the helper js. I have tried in the below way.

```
 getDate : function(component,event){
  component.set("v.showSpinner",true);
  var selected = event.getSource().get("v.label");
  var today = $A.localizationService.formatDate(new Date(), "MMMM dd yyyy");
  var da=today.getDate();
  da=da+30;
  component.set("v.today",today);
 }
```

In my component I am displaying the Date as

```
<ui:outputDext value="{!v.today}"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply `$A.localizationService.formatDate` method for already calculated date to get proper formatting.

In order to add 30 days to today use the following snippet:

```
var result = new Date();
result.setDate(result.getDate() + 30);
```

Your component should have attribute `<aura:attribute name="today" type="Date"/>`

helper code will look like

```
var result = new Date();
result.setDate(result.getDate() + 30);
var today = $A.localizationService.formatDate(result, "MMMM dd yyyy");
component.set("v.today", today);
```

Comment: Can I use a custom label or a variable in this piece of code instead of the integer value '30'? I need to make the number of days to be added configurable to that no change in code is required. ```javascript
var result = new Date();
result.setDate(result.getDate() + 30); // Custom label or var instead of 30
```

Comment: @VinayakSharma I tihnk this is really a new question, but it would make a useful addition here. I think you could do that using `$A.get("$Label.namespace.labelName")` in place of the 30, but try it out and if it works we could add it to this answer.